# How to set up wired network?

Tags: networking

I have cable network connection, so plz tel me how to setup wired network in Ubuntu? I mean Where to put what IP address, IP4 setting etc,Thanks.

Comment: Most Internet Service Providers (ISPs) provide the capability to automatically assign the IP address and other settings to a system when it is connected to their network. Do you need to enter the configuration data manually, or are you just not sure what to do? It would help if you would update your question with more information about your "cable network" so we have a better idea what type of help you are asking for. There are too many possibilities to bother guessing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click the Network Manager icon in the system notification area and click Edit Connections.
2. Click the Wired tab, select the connection and click Edit.
3. Click the IPv4 Settings tab and choose Manual from the Method drop down list.
4. Click Add and enter your IP address and other details. Enter the address of your DNS server too.
5. Click Apply. The network should now connect if you entered the settings correctly.